# How can i make this circuit to switch between two terminals?

Tags: switches, switching, component-selection, toggle-switch

I want to make a circuit so that with a push of a button(hardware one of any kind) i can switch this
[image]

to this

[image]

Using micro-controllers is also an option just as a passthrough

Comment: What are the current and voltage of these wires?

Comment: 5V they all operate on 5V

Comment: If these are USB signals then you need to state that in the question and add the USB tag. The data signals are not 5 V and they are probably >= 12 Mbps. This is significant and will be a major problem with your plan. See [here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/switching-in-usb-consumer-applications.html#:~:text=The%20USB%20standard%20specifies%20three,full%2D%2C%20and%20high%20speeds.).

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTm0th.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. To switch four signals two ways you need a 4-pole, double-throw switch.*

[image]

*Figure 2. 4PDT switches are available in various types including toggle, slider and rotary. (Google image source.)*

Comment: Can i do it with 2 DPDT switches because 4 pole double throw switches are currently not available?

Comment: Of course, but you need to consider what happens if they're not switched simultaneously.

Comment: Lets just say that this is a USB wire and im trying to make so that i can quickly switch between devices by connecting the keyboard and mouse to usb female ports and distribute to two different pc's or laptop in way visualised by the circuit with a switch will the DPDT circuit work for that

Comment: Your question didn't say anything about USB so this has been a waste of time. Switching USB signals like this is most likely to cause problems because of the high frequency signals. Use a KVM (keyboard-video-mouse) switching unit instead. Please give context when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

If these wires are 1-way only (input or output), then you can use 4 of two input/output mux (input) or demux (output) to control 4 wires with 1 digital pin (SELECT). I showed how you can make it for input lines in the circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJUe9m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>